# Transfer from asset pallets with generated pallet account

Tags: assets, transfer, origin, accountid

I want to create a pallet account and then store assets using pallet assets in it, but I have a problem withdrawing assets from the pallet account because you can't transfer from pallet assets unless there is an origin call for the account you want to transfer from, and there is no origin for the pallet account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you create this "pallet account"?

Take a look at how the Treasury pallet creates its account:

```rust
fn build(&self) {
    // Create Treasury account
    let account_id = <Pallet<T, I>>::account_id();
    let min = T::Currency::minimum_balance();
    if T::Currency::free_balance(&account_id) < min {
        let _ = T::Currency::make_free_balance_be(&account_id, min);
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cbd8f1b56fd8ab9af0d9317432cc735264c89d70/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L261-L271

Specifically, the `account_id()` function:

```rust
/// The account ID of the treasury pot.
pub fn account_id() -> T::AccountId {
    T::PalletId::get().into_account_truncating()
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cbd8f1b56fd8ab9af0d9317432cc735264c89d70/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L509-L515

If you follow the trail all the way, you will find the actual function that creates the account:

```rust
fn into_sub_account_truncating<S: Encode>(&self, sub: S) -> T {
    (Id::TYPE_ID, self, sub)
        .using_encoded(|b| T::decode(&mut TrailingZeroInput(b)))
        .expect("All byte sequences are valid `AccountIds`; qed")
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cbd8f1b56fd8ab9af0d9317432cc735264c89d70/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L1553

At the end of the day, this account can be used just like any other account in Substrate.

Comment: I have created it like this but wen i want to use transfer in pallet assets it only accept origin from dont accept account id

Comment: I see your point. Perhaps consider using `frame_system::RawOrigin::Signed(account_id)`. Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b3d9f3c57e7f799d49442e3456614431f2d0e51a/frame/proxy/src/lib.rs#L783).

Comment: Thanks you.worked like magic